# Login to wireless network with WPA password on Ubuntu Server

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, ubuntu-server

Is it at all possible to login to a wireless network with a WPA password on Ubuntu Server with no Window System?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup, [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=263136) post is a bit older but gives you the idea.

You have to use wpa_supplicant.